# Str/Int type error when printing from Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write some results from an array of strings to a file. The list is strings that actually contain numbers, which I'd like to divide by 1000. If I save the resulting conversion to a variable, I can print it to a file no problem. However, if I try to do the same exact thing in one line, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Any idea what's going on? Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
str_list = ['45000', '45500', '50000', '55000']
indx = 2

o = open('Output_file.dat', 'w')
```

This works....

```
x = float(str_list[indx])/1000
o.write('%4.1f\t' % x)
```

This does not

```
o.write('%4.1f\t' % float(str_list[indx])/1000)
```

Obvious short term workaround is to use the first syntax, but I'd like to understand what's going on and why the second doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%` is evaluated first:

```
o.write('%4.1f\t' % float(str_list[indx])/1000)
```

Is like (notice parenthesis):

```
o.write(('%4.1f\t' % float(str_list[indx]))/1000)
```

You want:

```
o.write('%4.1f\t' % (float(str_list[indx])/1000))
```

Comment: Ahhhh, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to put brackets around the `float(str_list[indx])/1000` part

```
o.write('%4.1f\t' % (float(str_list[indx])/1000))
```

Otherwise the program will try to divide a string by `1000`